# Preserve menu bar above page after click to retrieve the page

Tags: html, css

I created a menu using CSS , click one item in menu bring up a page , how do display the page  with menu still intact above the page, can this be done using CSS ?

I created the menu using html file and css file

Thanks in advance
Brian

Comment: If you want to use only HTML & CSS and not a server-side language like PHP, your only viable choice is to copy / paste your menu code on each page.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].